# Cloudwatch metrics never returning any results

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

I've been trying to get a simple application going that returns some cloudwatch metrics.  I've tried 3 different web examples and none are returning any data.  I can see the data on the AWS console. Perhaps someone can spot my error or point me to a simple example that is know to work?

The principal I want to achieve is:  I want to know when our application gets close to its dynamoDB read/write limits and then increase them.  I assume I need to write some thread that polls asking for stats, and if it reaches say 80% of capacity, increases the limits.

```
private static void findCloudWatchData() throws InterruptedException {
    AmazonCloudWatchClient cloudWatch = new AmazonCloudWatchClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(key, secret));
    cloudWatch.setEndpoint("monitoring.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com");

    GetMetricStatisticsRequest getMetricStatisticsRequest = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest();

    GregorianCalendar g = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 9, 17, 12, 0);

    getMetricStatisticsRequest.setStartTime(g.getTime());
    g.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2);
    getMetricStatisticsRequest.setEndTime(g.getTime());

    getMetricStatisticsRequest.setNamespace("AWS/DynamoDB");
    getMetricStatisticsRequest.setMetricName("SuccessfulRequestLatency");
    getMetricStatisticsRequest.setPeriod(5*60);

    Dimension tableDimension = new Dimension();
    tableDimension.setName("TableName");
    tableDimension.setValue("personalisation.user_favourite-int");

    Dimension operationDimension = new Dimension();
    operationDimension.setName("Operation");
    operationDimension.setValue("Query");

    getMetricStatisticsRequest.setDimensions(Arrays.asList(tableDimension, operationDimension));

    Collection<String> statistics = new ArrayList<String>();
    statistics.add("Average");

    getMetricStatisticsRequest.setStatistics(statistics);
    getMetricStatisticsRequest.setUnit(StandardUnit.Count);

    //results
    GetMetricStatisticsResult result = cloudWatch.getMetricStatistics(getMetricStatisticsRequest);
    System.err.println(result.getDatapoints().size());  //this returns 0 always
    for (Datapoint p : result.getDatapoints()) {
        System.out.println(p.getTimestamp() + " " + p.getAverage());
    }
 }
```

Comment: can't you use alarms for this?

Comment: possibly, this is sort of the programatic equivalent of an alarm.  Is there any way I can get an Alarm to call a java process?  I've only seen the ability to send someone emails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem.  If i change "SuccessfulRequestLatency" to this:

```
    getMetricStatisticsRequest.setMetricName("ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits");
```

Or
        getMetricStatisticsRequest.setMetricName("ConsumedReadCapacityUnits");

and set the date like this:

```
    now.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -5);
    getMetricStatisticsRequest.setEndTime(now.getTime());
    now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
    getMetricStatisticsRequest.setStartTime(now.getTime());
```

It starts to return data.  Embarrassingly, I've used the date range incorrectly, and assumed month=9 was Sept, when in fact month=8 is September.  Dynamo does not throw any invalid range exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I suggested in the comments, you may rely on CloudWatch alarms for this. It will avoid you the pain of running you own monitoring tool.

You can attach '[actions](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/CHAP_Glossary.html#glossary_action)' to alarm. One of the actions is `SNS topic`. `SNS` in turn can be used to trigger HTTP(S) call, send JSON, feed `SQS`, ...

This may be a bit more work work to setup but I believe it will be much, much easier to maintain. Btw, you will easily fit in the free Tier.

Comment: Thanks - Alerts were my 1st attempt at this, but I was having problems with them initially (perhaps I was too new to them).  Also I didnt realise you could use SNS, I thought it was just email.  I have managed to solve why i was not getting data back now, but I will investigate this route you have suggested again. It may be a better way of doing things.

Comment: After some further testing, I can't seem to find any alarm that suits my needs.  I'm looking to increase the rates when it hits a certain % (like 80%) - but the only alarms I can see, seem to be absolute values like "1000 hits/5 minutes"

Comment: You can configure an alarm when you reach x% (recommended is 80%) of the provisioned throughput. The interface for this is on the DynamoDB admin tool, not the CloudWatch one :)

Comment: Have you done this?  I just tested it out and it didnt work.  It thinks 80% is 0.8 of an absolute value.  "Threshold Crossed: 1 datapoint (525.0) was greater than or equal to the threshold (0.8)." - we might be getting off the original topic.  I should prob ask a new SO question regarding this.

Comment: fyi I've asked a different question relating to this - if you have time it would be good to get your opinion.  Many Thx.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508594/how-do-i-create-an-alarm-to-detect-dynamodb-limits-have-reached-a-certain-percen