# How do I create an Alarm to detect DynamoDb limits have reached a certain percent and then increase it

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm writing a web application that has steadily increasing traffic through the day.  I'd like to create an Alarm that can detect if my read / write limits have reached a certain percentage (like 80%), and then increase that limit.  I will then decrease it again at midnight.

I've tried creating an Alarm - "Average" seems a bit useless and is always 1.0. "Sum" is more useful so I assume i should use this.  I also assume i should use Consumed Write/Read Capacity at the metric name.

Problems:

- Sum seems to use an absolute value of "Count" for its limits.  If my DynamoDB is set to 100 writes, and i setup an alarm for 80%, it checks if my writes exceed 0.8, not 80.
- I've setup an email topic, but this is not correct - I assume I need to create a function/controller which a topic can call.  How would i set this up and if you have 2 Amazon VM's, would both get called or just one? Or is this the wrong route and there is a standard action one can take on events to increase DynamoDB limits without coding anything. (my lack of SNS knowledge is probably showing here)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When running Amazon's wizard to create a table, it suggests to create an alarm at **80% threshold** and to link it to an **SNS topic**.

Under the hood, for R/W capacity of 1, this creates an alarm on

- ConsumedReadCapacityUnits >= 240 for 60 minutes
- ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits >= 240 for 60 minutes

`240 = 0.8*1*60*5` that is to say, `capacity(1) * seconds_in_5_minutes(300) * threshold(0.8)`. 60 minutes is the alarm period. You can shorten down to 5 min but this might increase the number of false positive.

In other words, the alarm is triggered every time the sum of the consumed capacity units on ranges of 5 min exceeds the 24 treshold for at least 1 hour.

note: 5 min corresponds to the sampling period.

In the **SNS** [console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/sns/home?#s=TopicDetails), you can add '**subscribers**' to a topic. They can be e-mails, HTTP(S) callbacks, ... This allow you to contact multiple human/machines.

Every time your scaling logic is triggered, you will need to use the API to automatically update the alarms using this formula.

Comment: Thanks, so if i set 80%.  Amazon does the calculation for me.  But if i chanage my R/W capacity, amazon wont automatically change the alarm.  I'd need to change it via an alarm update?  Also, If I do an HTTP callback - how would I know that it was Amazon calling me and not someone else (I assume there are some special secret headers)

Comment: FYI: I've raised an AWS forum query about this.  This mechanism doesnt work :( - possibly due to Alarm bugs?