# AmazonClientManager scan sometimes (often) returns nil

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have some records in DynamoDB. But the query ***[[AmazonClientManager ddb] scan:]*** sometimes takes too long to load and returns nil. What might be the possible causes of this problem? One thing I could guess is that this could be a network problem. I am not sure about that. But this happens very often.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with request taking up to 5 sec to complete. This delays were visible in CloudWatch using the "max" aggregation function. This showed it is a problem on Amazon side.

The support told us that 5 sec is the "failover" delay on their side. This indicates that one of DynamoDB partitions had "troubles" (there are a least 2 of them)

As Scan is not capable of "Strong consistency", I guess it is also not capable of failing over. CloudWatch statistics might be a good starting point to validate this hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. In this case we need to increase provisioning throughput? I am new to AWS. I have no idea about provisioning throughput. Can you please let me know what are these how/when to use UpdateTable API in our app? I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: If it's this issue, you'll see it in CW. In this case, it's a bug on Amazon side and it might be a good idea to let them know so they can fix it. "Provisionned throughput" roughly corresponds to a number of request/seconds (http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughputIntro.html).

Comment: Regarding Provisioning Throughput: Can I adjust the throughput manually if my app is live? Or I need to use UpdateTable API? If I need to use UpdateTable API, which case I need to use this API? Is there any delegates/notifications in the app to do this? Please help me!

Comment: 'UpdateTable' is *the* API for updating the throughput. You can use it "manually" from AWS console or from anywhere in your program. It will not block the table. If you need more precision, I suggest you this page http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_UpdateTable.html and/or another question :)

Comment: Great. But, while my app is running, how will I know that when to update the table using UpdateTable API?

Comment: You can set an alarm on CloudWatch. You may be interested in reading question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508594/how-do-i-create-an-alarm-to-detect-dynamodb-limits-have-reached-a-certain-percen for this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the throughput capacity for the particular table was exceeded. So got *nil* after the 7 auto retries. Thank you everyone for your help!